# tabhost inside fragment not loading first time

Tags: android

I have one fragment in which I am setting tabhost widget with three tabs each have fragment.
When ever first time I come to this fragment first tab not loading first child fragment but after click on another tab and return on first tab then it is loading first child fragment.
Also I have little confusion that what will be the third parameter in tabhost.setup() method.It should be the layout of parent fragment which handles tabs or the layout of first child fragment.

Here is my code for parent fragment

```
public class MyStoreFragment extends Fragment implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    View rootView;

    public MyStoreFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       // rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_store,container, false);
      //  mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
       // mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),R.layout.fragment_my_store);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("new").setIndicator("NEW"), NewBookFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("trending").setIndicator("TRENDING"),FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("explore").setIndicator("EXPLORE"),FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FCF4E7"));
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FCF4E7"));

        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DF4426"));
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F6CFC2"));
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E03C20"));
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E03C20"));


//       TODO To set height and width properly of tab widget
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams();
//        params.width = 128;
        params.height = 50;
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(params );
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(params );
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setLayoutParams(params );


//        for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
//            TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
//            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#DA4426"));
//        }
        return mTabHost;

    }
```

Comment: Use Fragment pager with tabs instead using this, to use inside fragment.

Comment: but layout requirement is three tabs and also  my parent fragment inside navigation drawer

Comment: Follow this [Tutorial](https://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/)